# Why is the Emacs icon missing on OS X?

Tags: macos, emacs

I build emacs from source occasionally, and I notice that the icon, instead of being the nice [image: official Emacs icon], is instead the default this-app-has-no-icon icon.  Do I need to do something non-obvious to get the nice icon?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue although I did not build from source. It seemed to be that I would launch the application (this case emacs) and it would be in the doc obviously. Well while in this state I would scroll through my Apps folder and notice the Emacs folder had a circle with a line going through it, weird! So I closed the app and restarted it then the icon showed as should. Hope this helps, I know it's odd but it helped me.

Comment: That's not quite it ... as far as I can tell, that circle-with-the-line is OS X's way of warning you that the app isn't trusted; when you open such an app, you get a popup from the OS saying "This executable is from the Internet and thus contains cooties".  Once you've acknowledged that warning, the circle-with-the-line goes away.

Comment: hmmm thats odd because i get the circle with the line going through it after it is already installed an i accepted that warning. I never thought of that though. I have never built from source but is it possible you may have omitted or overidden the icon by mistake? I am sure you have already investigated that avenue though